# Distortion Analysis for OpAmp integrator

Tags: operational-amplifier, integrator, distortion

Is there a reference for distortion analysis of an opamp interator:

[image]

where the amplifier has finite gain a1 and a third order distortion coefficient a3 such that the open loop voltage can be described as vo = a1 vx + a3 vx^3?

Suppose C is replaced by Rf, then the distortion is frequency independent and using Taylor series and coefficient comparison, the new coefficients can be found as:

```
vo = b1*vi + b3*vi^3 (closed loop)
vo = a1 vx + a3 vx^3 (open loop)
(vi-vx)/R = (vx-vo)/Rf ->
vx = vi Rf/(R+Rf) + vo R/(R+Rf)

b1 = a1 Rf/(Rf+(a1+1)R)
b3 = a3 Rf^3 (R+Rf)/(Rf+(a1+1)R)^4
```

Now I can do the same thing by replacing Rf with 1/sC and arrive at:

```
b1 = a1/(1 + sRC(1 + a1)) = H1(s)
b3 = a3(1 + sRC)/(1 + sRC(1 + a1))^4 = H3(s)
```

Suppose I enter a single tone at f1 = 1 MHz then I should get a third order distortion (filtered) at f2 = 3 MHz and evaluate the HD3 as

```
HD3 = 1/4 abs(H3(j*2*pi*1e6))/abs(H3(j*2*pi*3e6)) * vi^2
```

but the result is different from what I get with the circuit simulator. Hence I am afraid the situation is more complex here (even with just one tone) and I am looking for a reference where this has been worked out.

Comment: "Suppose C is replaced by Rf, then the distortion is frequency independent " Not hardly. At the least, you'll run into slew rate distortion at high frequencies and amplitudes. "High" depends on the op amp.

Comment: Of course I assume everything ideal (small signal) and no slew rate for the amplifier.